# 1 million concurrent database connections

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-spanner

In https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/quotas, it mentioned that "Cloud Run services are limited to 100 connections to a Cloud SQL database.". Assume I deploy my service as Cloud Run, what's the right way to handle 1 million concurrent connections? Can cloud spanner enables this - I can't find documentation discussing maximum concurrent connections on cloud spanner maximum concurrent connection with Cloud Run.

Comment: Do you **really** need 1 million concurrent connections? Why can't you separate them or serialize some of the work? Or does it really come at the same time?

Comment: 1 million of concurrent connection to the database? Wow, what's your app?

Comment: I am not aware of any database that handles a million concurrent connections. With proper client design, connection pooling, and caching, a million concurrent connections is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want Cloud Run to handle a million concurrent connections, or do you want Cloud SQL to handle a million concurrent connections?

If you want Cloud SQL to handle a million concurrent connections, you are probably wrong. Check out [this article about Pool sizing](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing) (it's on a Java repo, but is general enough to apply to all connection pooling). If you are at the point where you need a million concurrent connections, you would need to invest in more advanced architectures (such as sharding).